# Ajax cache, how to implement?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I've got this piece of jquery code that accesses a url via get and inserts the data to a container. How can I change it to actually cache the requested url and the returned data, so it won't load the url all over again if it's called more than once, but instead serve the cached data?

This is the code

```
_loadAjaxContents = function (href) {
  var dfr = new $.Deferred();

  $.get(href, function (data) {
    self.$expanderInner.html(data);
    dfr.resolve();
  });

  return dfr.promise();
}
```

Comment: You could try using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: thanx for the link, it is helpful, I might pull it off with the instructions in there.

Comment: cache the results for what duration? 1) Only during this page, 2) Only for some period of time or 3) Forever.

Comment: for some predefined period, lets say 2 weeks

Comment: Well if the server sets the correct caching header, the browser will pull from the cache and not the server.

Comment: you're talking about expires headers right? well, I'm looking into that solution as well, thanx for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

well I made it by means of localstorage thanx to the link posted by aug.

Here is the changed function

```
       _loadAjaxContents = function (href) {
      var dfr = new $.Deferred();


        function populateStorage(href,data){
            localStorage.setItem('url-' + href, data);
        }         

            var aValue = false;   
        if(aValue = localStorage.getItem('url-' + href)) {
            self.$expanderInner.html(aValue);
            dfr.resolve();                      
        } else {
            $.get(href, function (data) {
                self.$expanderInner.html(data);
                dfr.resolve();
                populateStorage(href,data);
            });                 
        }  

      return dfr.promise();
    }
```

Comment: Why not set the appropriate headers on your server and let the browser cache it automatically?  No client side code needs to make that work in all browsers.

Comment: i do not know how to do that for specific urls

Comment: If you want help with that, you will have to start by explaining to us what your server environment is.  All http server infrastructures can set specific headers on specific responses and that's all you need to do.

Comment: well atm I'm on localhost, using apache 2.4.9. When the project goes live it will be on litespeed 5.something (do not remember exact version) on CentOS 6.6 with cpanel

Comment: What programming environment are you using for the web server?  What is the code that responds to these Ajax requests that you want cached?  There are many different tools you could be using with Apache.  Is it PHP?  Java?  Python?  A framework?

Comment: Here's a [pretty good article](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) about setting caching headers.  It seems like whatever PHP code is generating the Ajax response can just set the appropriate cache headers for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Since localstorage can be removed only by the user (clear browser cache) and in my case I want the cache to basically expire after a predefined amount of time and the ajax call to be remade after that time, I changed the above code to allow for exactly that. In this case I put the time limit to 2 minutes.

```
       _loadAjaxContents = function (href) {
  var dfr = new $.Deferred();


    function populateStorage(href,data,ajaxtime){
        localStorage.setItem('url-' + href, data);
        localStorage.setItem('url-time-' + href, ajaxtime);
    }         

        var aValue = false;
        var ajaxtime = $.now();

    if(Storage !== void(0)){
    if(aValue = localStorage.getItem('url-' + href)) {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('url-time-' + href) < (ajaxtime - 120000 ) ) {
            $.get(href, function (data) {
                self.$expanderInner.html(data);
                dfr.resolve();
                populateStorage(href,data,ajaxtime);
            });             
        }
        else {
            self.$expanderInner.html(aValue);
            dfr.resolve();                      
        }                   
    } else {
        $.get(href, function (data) {
            self.$expanderInner.html(data);
            dfr.resolve();
            populateStorage(href,data,ajaxtime);
        });                 
    }
    }
    else {
        $.get(href, function (data) {
            self.$expanderInner.html(data);
            dfr.resolve();
        });         
    }

  return dfr.promise();
}
```

The localstorage isn't really expiring, it is just being replaced with new values